# How to deal with multiple spilled values as operands for a single instruction?

Tags: compiler-construction, register-allocation

I want to implement the [*Linear Scan Register Allocation* algorithm proposed by Poletto and Sarkar](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~hchoi/teaching/cs160d/linearscan.pdf). It is pretty straight-forward and assigns either a register or a stack location to every live interval.

> A stack location is only assigned to an interval when the number of active intervals that have been assigned registers is equal to the number of registers (i.e. there are no more free registers).

The algorithm:

[image: Linear Scan Register Allocator]

Suppose an x86 instruction `add a, b` where `a` and `b` are variables that have both been assigned a *stack location* (spilled) by this algorithm. There is no way to encode this instruction with *two* memory operands, so at least one of the operands must reside in a register. I would insert a `mov REG, a` before the instruction, but as I understand the algorithm there are *no* free registers at this point in the code. How is this typically solved?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/vee05/full_papers/p132-wimmer.pdf) (in section 7), the linear scan register allocation algorithm needs to reserve a scratch register.

> This has a negative effect on architectures with few registers such as the Intel IA-32 architecture because it increases the register pressure. In particular, it is not possible to implement the algorithm without reserving a scratch register: When a spilled interval is used by an instruction requiring the operand in a register, the interval must be temporarily reloaded to the scratch register.

Let's say you have the following assembly and 3 registers:

```
mov t1, 1
mov t2, 2
mov t3, 3
mov t4, 4
mov t5, 5
add t4, t5
push t1
push t2
push t3
push t4
push t5
```

You'll assign the first two registers (keeping the third one for spilling):

```
mov r1, 1
mov r2, 2
mov r3, 3
mov [sp + 4], r3
mov r3, 4
mov [sp + 8], r3
mov r3, 5
mov [sp + 12], r3
mov r3, [sp + 8]
add r3, [sp + 12]
push r1
push r2
mov r3, [sp + 4]
push r3
mov r3, [sp + 8]
push r3
mov r3, [sp + 12]
push r3
```

There seem to be an alternative not requiring a scratch register, which is called splitting, but I have not investigated it yet, but the aforementioned paper describes it.

Another idea would be to use a different algorithm that re-run itself with the new instructions generated by spilling and using a spill heuristic that will spill longer ranges, so that the new temporaries generated by spilling won't be spilled again.