# Spilling a symbol doesn't improve colorability

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, cpu-registers, intermediate-language

Say I have this intermediate representation of some code:

```
t1 = 1
t2 = 2
t3 = 3

t4 = t1 + t2
t5 = t3 + t4

use t5
```

The ultimate goal is to do register assignment using only two ARM registers, `r0` and `r1`, and possibly spill some symbols.

The first step is to compute live ranges for each instruction:

```
t1 = 1       |
t2 = 2       | t1
t3 = 3       | t1, t2

t4 = t1 + t2 | t1, t2, t3 (this is going to become a problem)
t5 = t3 + t4 | t3, t4

use t5       | t5
```

### Register interference graph

```
              t2
            /    \     
           /      \    
          /        \   
        t1----------t3
                    | 
                    | 
        t5          t4
```

### Register assignment via graph coloring

Now use Chaitin's algorithm on it to color it with the *two* registers:

1. Find node with fewer than 2 edges

   1. Found => `t5`
   2. Remove it from the graph
   3. Push it onto the stack: `[t5]`
2. Find node with fewer than 2 edges

   1. Found => `t4`
   2. Remove it from graph, push: `[t5, t4]`
3. No nodes with fewer than 2 edges! (we're looking at the `t1 - t2 - t3` triangle)

   1. Pick one at random (or with the highest degree (2 for all remaining nodes)) => `t3` (this might be a problem)
   2. Remove it from graph, push: `[t5, t4, t3]`
4. Find node with fewer than 2 edges

   1. Found `t2`
   2. Remove it from graph, push: `[t5, t4, t3, t2]`
5. Push the last node: `[t5, t4, t3, t2, t1]`

Now assign registers in reversed order:

1. Pop symbol => `t1`

   1. Conflicting nodes: none
   2. Assign: `t1 => r0`
   3. Put `t1` back in the graph
2. Pop `t2`

   1. Conflicting nodes: `{t1: r0}`
   2. We have one more free register
   3. Assign: `t2 => r1`
   4. Put `t2` back in the graph
3. Pop `t3`

   1. Conflicting nodes: `{t1: r0, t2: r1}`
   2. OOPS! No more free registers!
   3. Spill it => `t3 => m0`
   4. Put `t3` back in the graph
4. No more spills required!

Final assignment:

```
t1 -> r0
t2 -> r1
t3 -> m0 (spilled)
t4 -> r0 (or r1)
t5 -> r0 (or r1)
```

### Inserting spills

Now, as per [this](http://user.it.uu.se/~kostis/Teaching/KT1-11/Slides/lecture16.pdf) (slide 29) and [this](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/106108052/module5/global-reg-all-3.pdf) (slide 4):

> Before each operation that uses [the spilled symbol `t3`], insert `t3 := load m0`
>
> After each operation that defines [the spilled symbol `t3`], insert `store t3, m0`

Let's do this and also compute the live ranges:

```
t1 = 1       |
t2 = 2       | t1

t3 = 3       | t1, t2
// STORE
store t3, m0 | t1, t2, t3 (STILL 3 SYMBOLS!)

t4 = t1 + t2 | t1, t2

// LOAD
t3 = load m0 | t4
t5 = t3 + t4 | t3, t4

use t5       | t5
```

### Problem

As you can see, we still have an instruction where three symbols interfere, and we'll also get the same RIG as before.

So the spill didn't work!

Now, I brute-forced the possible candidates for spilling by hand and found out that the RIG remains *not* 2-colorable if we spill any *one* symbol, but it becomes 2-colorable if we spill any of these pairs of symbols:

- `t1` and `t3`
- `t2` and `t3`

...and also `t1`, `t2` and `t3`, but spilling only two symbols looks simpler.

### Actual question

*How do I decide what to spill?* What heuristic do I use? I'd also like the algorithm to do global register assignment, so plain live ranges and linear-scan assignment (as opposed to building the RIG) seems to be a pretty cumbersome approach.

Also, if I re-run the same algorithm on the code with spills, the result will be "spill `t3`" again, even though it's been done already, so the code will loop forever. Even more, if I continue spilling `t3` and inserting `load`/`store` code, I'll get more and more instructions where `t1`, `t2` and `t3` interfere, so the situation will be getting worse.

And that's assuming that I can just `t3 = load m0`, while on ARM (that I'm targeting) `m0` should be stored in its own register first.

Comment: Maybe the last paragraph of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446878/how-to-deal-with-multiple-spilled-values-as-operands-for-a-single-instruction/56971134#56971134) will help you, i.e. use a spill heuristic that spills longer ranges, so that the new temporaries generated by spilling won't be spilled again.

Comment: @antoyo, this seems to work after running the linear-scan algorithm on the last piece of code (with `t3` spilled) and choosing to spill `t1` as the symbol with the longest live range so far (at instruction `store t3, m0`). But the RIG approach loses all information about a symbol's live range (right?), so looks like I can't use this here. I could as well switch to linear-scan, but I already have a working graph-coloring allocator (that can't spill), and I'm not terribly excited about writing a new allocator

Comment: So, what I used in [my own graph-coloring register allocator](https://github.com/antoyo/tiger-rs/blob/20d4f384a1bdd788d710cdb38ede48e18ae5963b/tiger/src/color.rs#L384) for the spill cost was the degree of the node (i.e. the number of neighbors) which is kind of correlated to the live range. You could try that.

Comment: @antoyo, I'm kinda using this implicitly already. See step 2.1 in the first list: "Pick one at random (or with the highest degree) => `t3`". So I end up with that `t1 - t2 - t3` triangle after popping off `t4` and `t5`, and there all three nodes have degree 2, so again I don't know which one to choose